# cannot run an expect script from bash

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I'm trying to call an expect script from bash but I get the following error:

```
+ cd /usr/local/sbin/myscripts
+ exec transfer_single_cert.expct jw.jwebster
./resend_keys.sh: line 131: exec: transfer_single_cert.expct: not found
```

This is the bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

...other code
cd /usr/local/sbin/myscripts
exec transfer_single_cert.expct $usern
```

Any ideas why that would give the above error?
The filename is correct.

I also tried

```
exec /usr/bin/bash /usr/local/sbin/myscripts/transfer_single_cert.expct $usern
./transfer_single_cert.expct $usern
```

Comment: not sure I understand, what about `expect transfer_single_cert.expct` AFAIK, expect files need to be called with expect.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is: by default current directory isn't in the search `PATH` that's why `transfer_single_cert.expct` can't be found.

So invoke `transfer_single_cert.expct` as `./transfer_single_cert.expct` (and make sure that it has executable bit (`chmod +x transfer_single_cert.expct`) and the first line of the expect script is [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) with the correct location of `expect`.
Or just use `expect transfer_single_cert.expct`.